# Unable to parse date Apr 15, 2020 12:14:17 AM to LocalDatetime

Tags: java, java-8, localdate

I am trying to parse Apr 15, 2020 12:14:17 AM to LocalDateTime using

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM DD',' YYYY h:mm:ss a")
```

I am getting exception

```java
    Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Apr 15, 2020 12:14:17 AM' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=4, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2020, DayOfYear=15},ISO resolved to 00:14:17 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at com.paypal.Test.main(Test.java:76)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this format having lower case for date and year.

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd',' yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
```

Answer (score 1):

your format string only contains one hour char. It should be like this:

```
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
```

Edit I fixed the format further , making `DD` and `YYYY` lowercase. Also you don't need to excape the comma, because it is not actual text.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Apr 15, 2020 12:14:17 AM' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=4, DayOfYear=15, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2020},ISO resolved to 00:14:17 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: don't use `DD`. use `dd` and perhaps `yyyy` instead.